# iTunes 10.3 thinks it's a version below? No ping, locked out from iphone sync

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, data-synchronization, ping

my iTunes thinks it's a version below for some reason

I have 10.3 installed (Finder says so, iTunes > About says so) but when I try go into ping it gives me the "See what you're missing, upgrade to 10.3" message - I hadn't worried about this too much before but I just updated my iPhone to the OS 5 beta and now iTunes is not letting me sync at all leaving me with a fairly useless and unsyncable iPhone and crippled iTunes.

I have tried re-installing iTunes (Yes I even deleted all the preference files) I have tried iTunes on another account on my macbook and it gives the same error.

Please help, I need to sync my iPhone!

Here is a screenshot of the Ping message: http://cl.ly/470n472Q2C442b2k0w3Z

Screenshot of the iphone sync message: http://cl.ly/0s3Z1q2g2Y0a29280V0W

Thanks

Comment: **Incorrect question title:** The error message says that the phone requires iTunes **10.5** — I presume the Developer iOS 5 beta installer package also installs a new iTunes, at least it did last year for iOS 4 beta. Current iTunes 10.3 was just released yesterday. Are you sure you installed everything correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in troubles. :(

How you updated your iphone to IOS5-beta without iTunes 10.5? Asking because iTunes 10.5 is only for developers now.

from the: http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/06/06/apple_says_devices_updated_to_ios_5_beta_cant_be_restored_to_earlier_versions.html

**In releasing several pieces of pre-release software -- iTunes 10.5, Apple TV 2 beta, Xcode 4.2 Preview and Lion Preview 4 -- to its developer community, Apple on Monday warned testers of its new iOS 5.0 software that any devices updated to the beta cannot be reverted or downgraded to previous versions.**

You need iTunes 10.5 - developer release yet - whats mean register yourself as developer for 99USD/year.

Comment: If this user installed an illegitimate iOS 5 beta (without a developer account), I have little sympathy.

Comment: Nope, it's a legit copy - I'll try download itunes 10.5

Comment: 10.5 fixed it lol embarrassing